# Vue testing the message of the tooltip

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, jestjs, vuex

First the idea is to test the tooltip messages, in this case I have two options, when the user is the owner and the other when he is not the owner. In the case where the user is the owner, it is possible to verify the message.

However, when the user is not the owner, I have problems. As I understand it, the problem occurs because the v-icon is disabled. In this case, the v icon is disabled because the user is not the owner.

Since the v icon is disabled, this **helpIcon.trigger('focus')** command does not seem to take any action.

```
<v-tooltip
  bottom
>
  <template #activator="{ on }">
    <span v-on="on">
      <v-icon
        :disabled="!isOwner"
        v-on="on"
        @click="dialog = !dialog"
      >
        delete
      </v-icon>
    </span>
  </template>

  <div>
    <span
      v-if="isOwner"
      data-test="tooltipOwner-text"
    >
      Remove
    </span>

    <span
      v-else
      data-test="tooltipNotOwner-text"
    >
      You are not the owner of this namespace
    </span>
  </div>
</v-tooltip>
```

The test:

```
it('Show message tooltip to user doesn\'t owner', async (done) => {
const icons = wrapper.findAll('.v-icon');
expect(icons.length).toBe(1);

const helpIcon = icons.at(0);
expect(helpIcon.text()).toEqual('delete');

helpIcon.trigger('focus');
await wrapper.vm.$nextTick();
requestAnimationFrame(() => {
  expect(wrapper.find('[data-test="tooltipNotOwner-text"]').text()).toEqual('You are not the owner of this namespace');
  done();
});
```

The error:

```
[vue-test-utils]: find did not return [data-test="tooltipNotOwner-text"], cannot call text() on empty Wrapper
```

Comment: why do you disable `v-tooltip` activator, if you want it to show `tooltipNotOwner-text` when user is not the owner?

Comment: Because when the click occurs, an action is performed, only the owner can perform it.

Comment: disable only the click if not the owner, not the entire icon.